# XSLT with Saxon and EXSLT.org's RegEx

Tags: java, xml, regex, xslt, saxon

I have this XML and XSL which when run via a standalone XML processor that was created in an windows environment, generates a proper .html file.

I'm looking transforming the XML with the XSL file in Linux using Saxon on the command-line.

The XSL makes use of an external .xsl that includes some RegEx functionality, this is where the EXSLT.org comes into play. There is a regexp.test.msxsl.xsl file that is included.

Though when you run java -jar /path/to/saxon.jar -O test.html my.xml my.xsl

I get

> Error at xsl:choose on line 63 of file:my.xsl:
>   The URI: 
>   http://exslt.org/regular-expressions does not identify an external
>   Java class Transformation Failed.

The windows source code is a C#. I'm only assuming that the external xsl file that includes the regex functionality is geared for a windows environment and not meant to be used with Java.

Essentially the XML portion is this

```
<xsl:when test="(string(@IfIs)="") or (not(regex:test(string($input_doc//inf[@id='5']), string(@IfIs), 'i')))">
```

Unless someone might know how I can do regex in XLST 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unless someone might know how I can do regex in XLST 2.0?

If you're just using regex in tests, use `matches()` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match)

The link above includes `tokenize()` and `replace()` as well.

If you have to do any complicated string manipulation, look at `xsl:analyze-string` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-analyze-string)

Answer (score 1):

EXSLT is essentially a set of specifications for function libraries, many of them providing stop-gap functionality for XSLT 1.0 processors that isn't needed in XSLT 2.0 because the necessary features became part of the standard. The EXSLT regex library wasn't implemented in Saxon because the XSLT 2.0 features were already available. A stylesheet that uses EXSLT functions (as yours does) will only work with processors that implement those functions.

Comment: So by going to XPATH2 to make use of their matches() function I can get rid of the EXSLT portion of my xsl correct? 

I need to figure out what else is going on. With the MS XSL Parser the XML/XSL used to use, I would get a 500kb file. With using Java CLI and Saxon, I am getting an 8MB file

Comment: I don't know the spec of regex:test() so it might be that it doesn't translate exactly to matches(), for example it might do an anchored rather than unanchored match. But there's almost certainly some way of using the XPath 2.0 regex capabilities to meet the requirement.